# Как запустить интент с ресурсом из приложения Android

Tags: android, java

Пытаюсь открыть файл ресурса в галереи. 
Пишу так

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.i1);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, null); 
            intent.setData(path);
            intent.setType("image/png"); 
            startActivity(intent);
```

Появляется диалог приложение галерея неожиданно остановлено.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

[ссылка на logCat](http://pastebin.com/wp9ZnMwK)

Comment: Версия андроида > 4? Где-то я уже видел эту проблему...

Comment: версия 2.3.3  А насчет решения не знаете существует ли оно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что ресурс всегда read-only и не может использоваться просто так сторонней аппой (`Intent`'ом).

Если делать правильно, то надо над своими ресурсами создавать `ContentProvider`, который возьмет на себя труд по публикации данных приложения сторонним `Intent`'ам